# Segmentation fault (core dumped) on bulk deletion of objects

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to delete large number of entries (approximately 1 million entries) from PostgreSQL database table. I am using a management command to execute this.

Using `Foo.objects.delete()` errors giving response as "Killed".

When I tried to delete it as batches of 10000, it deletes the first couple of batches and then results in error

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

I then tried giving a delay of a few seconds `time.sleep(10)`but to no effect. Please help.

Comment: `foo.objects.delete` won't work as `delete` is the one queryset function that requires you to use a filter or all, so what is the actual code you're using and what is the full traceback?

Comment: If you want to delete everything in a table, a better solution is probably to run a TRUNCATE in raw SQL or as a migration.

Comment: @Sayse Foo.objects.delete() has the same effect as Foo.objects.all().delete() right? Btw, I was able to delete it in batches of 100000. Probably it must have been a memory issue.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, but I actually wanted to delete the relations as well, which I think is not possible by truncating the table using raw SQL. Btw, I did manage to delete the table using ORM query itself. I think it was a memory issue. Thanks for your time anyway.